# select more than one value from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkboxlist

I have a list and inside that list, I can select more than one value. So I create a dropdown list of checkboxes.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form>
<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
        <select>
            <option>Select an option</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
        @{ 
            if (ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee == null || ((IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.ActiveUsersList>)ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee).Count() == 0)
            {
                @:<h3>No records were processed.</h3>

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var usr in ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee)
                    {                   
                        <label id="userName">@usr.EmployeeName</label>     
                        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" name="search_emp" id="search_emp" value=@usr.EmployeeName>
                @:
        }
        }
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

So I can select more than one value and then pass it to the JS function:

```
<div id="datePicker">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script name="select_date" id="select_date">

  $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          var userName = $(' .checked:checked').val();
         // var userName = $('search_emp').multiselect();
          console.log(userName);
          $.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  strUserName: userName,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
  </script>
  <button class="action" type="button" id="button_select">@Resources.Resources.ButtonFind</button>
```

Im using this line:

> var userName = $(' .checked:checked').val();

to get one value. My question is, how can I get more than one value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var values = $('.checked:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`

Comment: `.val()` returns multiple values as array if  `$('.checked:checked')` returns multiple checkboxes.

Comment: You need to loop over all checked elements with Jquery you can use many ways like `each() - filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning all those values as an array, you only need to loop through them.

Use .each() function for it